# MVC3 Route Contraints distinction between parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

for my website i am building up links dynamically from xml(-nodes). it so happens that most of the time, the links to productdetails are built up like this:

me.com/one/two/three/four/productdetail

there are some cases though where there is a fifth node after the fourth, so the link is:

me.com/one/two/three/four/five/productdetail

how can i, in my action method, distinguish this fifth 'segment' from a productdetail if they are both strings?

public ActionResult Products(string one, string two, string three, string four, string productdetail, string five = null)
{
}

i now have routes defined like this:

{controller}/{action}/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{productdetail}

{controller}/{action}/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{five}/{productdetail}

(where {one} till{five} are UrlParameter.Optional)

route constraints with regex doesnt seem to help since theyre both strings (and they can both be very similar strings even).

is this even possible?

Comment: whats wrong with having just the two routes exactly? this should work just fine

Comment: Aaron, it then maps the link for me.com/one/two/three/four/five/ mistakenly to me.com/one/two/three/four/productdetail...

Comment: ive edited my answer but basically, if both patterns are identical, then the framework has no way of distinguishing the routes. You need to use a constraint to distinguish this

Comment: ps you should accept an answer and/or upvote people for trying to help you... I think that your question has been answered :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this would be to register routes for 5 ,4,3 and 2 parameters. Register them in that order.

```
 {controller}/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{five}/{productdetail} 
 {controller}/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{productdetail} 
 {controller}/{one}/{two}/{three}/{productdetail} 
 {controller}/{one}/{two}/{productdetail}
```

You cant register a route for {controller}/{one}/{productdetail}  without creating a route constraint to make sure that {one} is not an action of {controller}.

I would strongly suggest that if you have lists of what options 1 - 5 COULD be that you create a custom route constraint that would validate them so you don't accidently match a route you didn't intend to but you should be safe with the above routes I've laid out.

Creating a IRouteConstraint isn't difficult. Below is some code that I've previously for a route constraint that would allow calling an action from a specific controller without needing to specify the controller. An example would be a controller called Home with an action for "About", this constraint would allow for you to call /about instead of /home/about.

It's relevant to what you want to do because it shows you how to do some validation to tell the difference between {one} and {action} should you need to.

The route constraint:

```
public class IsRootActionConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private List<string> _actions;

    public IsRootActionConstraint(): this( "homecontroller")
    {

    }
    public IsRootActionConstraint(string ControllerName)
    {
        Type _type = Assembly
                            .GetCallingAssembly()
                            .GetTypes()
                            .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller)) && type.Name.ToLower() == ControllerName.ToLower())
                            .SingleOrDefault();
        if (_type != null)
        {
            _actions = (from methods in _type.GetMethods() where typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(methods.ReturnType) select methods.Name.ToLower()).ToList();
        }
    }

    #region IRouteConstraint Members

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return _actions.Contains((values["action"] as string).ToLower());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And when you register your route in the global.asax:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { IsRootAction = new CAA.Utility.Constraints.IsRootActionConstraint() }  // Route Constraint
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In your case, validating that {one} doesn't match a route in {controller} shouldn't be too difficult. You could move the reflection code in to the Match method and use the name from the route values for controller to find actions.

Comment: i dont see how this solves the OP's question. he has two patterns that are identical. the patterns you listed each have different param counts, which is incorrect.

Comment: The OP had an issue with varying number of product attributes (1 - 5). He had something working that would allow four attributes but not a fifth. By setting up the routes in a specific order (The 5 route, then the 4 route, then the 3 route, then the 2 route) you can allow for up to 5 parameters. While my routes are missing the action (I must have been looking at someone elses route list instead of the OPs) the concept still applies. If the action is present in the route some of my route constraint doesn't apply BUT the concept of how to create a route constraint and do matching still does.

Comment: The IRouteConstraint can do conditional checking on any parameters in the route collection to see IF the URL is a match. It would be the IRouteConstraint that can tell the difference between {five} and {productdetail} but you would have to do some database validation in the Match method.

Comment: read his comments. he did not articulate the problem in his question. he essentially wants two identical routes with and without varying number of params. he also cannot use a constraint (so he claims) as there is no apparent way to differentiate the two routes from a value. Your answer is good, and it solves part of the problem, but it doesnt actually solve this fundamental problem. There is no way to do what he's asking :)

Comment: He didn't say he couldn't use route constraints. He said "route constraints with regex doesnt seem to help since theyre both strings" which is why I showed him how to use an IRouteConstraint which is capable of doing additional work when comparing the values in the URL to the route to see IF the values are attributes. What he wants to do CAN be done, its just a matter of creating the logic in "public bool Match" to look at the XML data to determine if the route data matches data in the XML Source and returning true/false.

Answer (score 0):

By having two separate routes, one with five elements, and another with four elements, these routes can just go to the same place. One passes through {five} the other doesn't.

EDIT: If both patterns are identical, then the only way is to use a constraint to distinguish the different values.

Comment: Aaron, thanks for your answer. So say, if i would have a productdetail called "phone1", but also a fifth segment called "phone1", there is no way to distinguish the routes? (regex seem useless for this). I'll have to take another approach then. This sure is a pitfall of the MVC3 framework then...

Comment: No worries. To answer your question, put yourself in the frameworks shoes. How would the framework know where to direct your request to? if the url patterns are the same, the framework just doesn't know which of the two routes to choose. possibly think about shuffling your url around, or finding a way for constraints to work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can made some changes to route declaration to meet your expectation.

1. Dont put one till five as optional parameters.
2. MapRoot **{controller}/{action}/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{five}/{productdetail}** should come before **{controller}/{action}/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{productdetail}**
3. Followed by default maproute.**{controller}/{action}/{id}** id being optional

Now

1. Request for **me.com/one/two/three/four/five/productdetail** will match
   first route only.
2. Request for **me.com/one/two/three/four/productdetail** will match
   second route only.

Comment: Hi Manas, that would work, but i need to also be able to go to 

me.com/one/two/three/four/five/ to show a list of productdetails. EDIT: i will try it without optional paramaters

Comment: EDIT2: without optional parameters theres no match for me.com/one/two/

Answer (score 0):

If, in your case, you cannot set route constraints, then your best option is to change a bit your routes so that ASP.NET MVC can know, for sure, which is your product detail argument in order to avoid any confusion with the optional {five}.

Have your product detail be preceded with some specific string that can NEVER happen in one till five values, for example:

```
{controller}/{action}/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/p/{productdetail}

{controller}/{action}/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{five}/p/{productdetail}
```

This will solve your problem.